# Why is my random password generator outputting the same string every time?

Tags: c#

```
string[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
                  "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
string current = "";
string[] newarr = new string [26];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int a = 0; a < 26 /*How many passwords*/; a++)
{
    while (current.Length < 5 /*Length of passwords*/)
    {
        current = current + alpha[rand.Next(26)];
    }

    newarr[a] = current;
    Console.WriteLine(newarr[a]);
}
```

The for loop is used to execute the code many times, thus providing many random strings, and the while loop is used to add a random digit to the password.

Comment: Read up on how to seed `Random`.

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your code using the **[free, awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: You're seeding your random correctly, the problem is you fill up current once and it's length is always >5 after that. Place a  current=string.Empty; after you write to console in the loop and you'll get the desired effect.

Comment: You never reset "current" variable, and only assign to it in the first iteration of the for loop. , and then for all iterations you assign it to newarr.

Comment: Came back to add a dotnetfiddle since the question was previously closed, but I guess it got reopened after I answered via comment. Anyway, here's a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GnekWC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're only setting `current` one time (until it's 5 characters long), and then continually adding it to an array.

If you add `current = string.Empty` after adding it to the `newarr` array (basically resetting `current` so it can be assigned a new value), you'll get the expected results.

Better yet, we should just declare `current` inside the loop, since we don't need it elsewhere. This way it gets reassigned at the beginning of each iteration.

As a side note, it's usually good to use the `Length` property of the array you're looping over as the bounds for the loop. This way, if someone makes the array smaller, you don't have to update all the loop values:

```
string[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

string[] passwords = new string[alpha.Length];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int a = 0; a < passwords.Length; a++)
{
    var password = "";

    while (password.Length < 5)
    {
        password = password + alpha[rand.Next(alpha.Length)];
    }

    passwords[a] = password;
    Console.WriteLine(passwords[a]);
}
```

Comment: +1, Also suggest declaring variable "current" inside of for loop, before while loop, which will also remove need to set to empty string at end of loop body.

Comment: @dugas great suggestion; added it